# Identifying the Alert executing the SQL Server Job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is an SQL Server Agent Job (Job_1)

Job_1 has 2 Alerts configured (Alert_1 and Alert_2) executing it

Job_1 has 1 step which calls stored procedure which takes one parameter as input

```
exec stored_procedure_1 '@param1'
```

Is there a way to pass the calling Alert's 'Message Text' (or some indicator of which alert triggered the job) as a parameter to stored_procedure_1

i.e. If Alert_1 triggers Job_1

```
exec stored_procedure_1 'Message From Alert_1'
```

or for Alert_2

```
exec stored_procedure_1 'Message From Alert_2'
```

I can achieve this by having one job per alert but that is not very practical when the number of alerts are larger

Comment: Dont put the message in the stored procedure? Put them in a table. Not sure I understand the questions. You want a error to bubble up automatically?

Comment: I want to call the stored procedure to do something with this information. I want the stored procedure to handle the logic so that the SQL Job Step will not require edits in the future.

Comment: Even if I were to put the information in some table, I will still need to know the Alert which executed the job

Comment: `declare @Alert1 varchar(200) = select Alert1 from AlertTable`, then pass to `exec stored_procedure_1  @Alert1`